# Where to find git release notes?

Tags: git

I'm having trouble finding what's new in the latest release of git. For example, I could not find any info on git's main github [page](https://github.com/git/git).

Where can one find git's release notes (ideally for all releases, but at least the latest one)?

Comment: start at https://github.com/git/git/ and click on Documentation then RelNotes (or clone the repository and look at the files locally, which is what I usually prefer).

Comment: Yes, I found it eventually, but it was so surprisingly not easy (at least to my small brain) that I decided to add a question and then answer it.

Comment: For the lasts version, GitHub blog is providing [some highlights](https://github.blog/?s=Highlights+from+Git) (With inside the links to the release notes)

Comment: doth thou not know of the actual [git](https://git-scm.com/) site? o.O

Comment: I do, no release notes there.

Comment: @tymtam there's a link under the release version called release notes [see here](https://imgur.com/a/SWE6jNG)

Comment: For those reviewing this for being reopened, please see the following Meta post [When is a resource request on-topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/385479)

Answer (score 4):

#### Git

Git release notes can be found under [Documentation/RelNotes](https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/Documentation/RelNotes) folder on github.

You can get to the files by going to git's main repo at https://github.com/git/git and then to Documentation folder, then RelNotes folder. Please note:

1. 2.23 is more recent than 2.4, 2.10, etc.
2. The files are ordered alphabetically so the latest release is **not** at the bottom.

The number of the latest release can be found by going to the [Releases](https://github.com/git/git/releases) tab in the git repo.

---

#### Git for Windows

The release notes for Git for Windows are [in github](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/)

You can get there via:

1. https://gitforwindows.org/ -> All Releases; or
2. https://github.com/git-for-windows/git -> Releases tab

Answer (score 1):

For the lasts version, GitHub blog is providing [some highlights](https://github.blog/?s=Highlights+from+Git)

For the last release at the moment (2.23):

https://github.blog/2019-08-16-highlights-from-git-2-23/

Inside, there is the link to the release notes (which is published in a mailing list):
https://public-inbox.org/git/xmqqy2zszuz7.fsf@gitster-ct.c.googlers.com/